# CMakeList builds two binaries from one class with different settings

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm learning using CMake.
I have a class A (a.h) as follows.

```
class A {
public:
using MyArray = std::array<double, 4>;
...
}
```

Note that here the size of MyArray is 4.

I'm using CMakeList to build an executable file.

```
...
add_library(mylib
a.h a.cpp)

add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp mylib)
...
```

My question is, how could I build two executable files: one is `myapp` with MyArray size fixed at 4 (as above); and another one `myapp-20` with MyArray size fixed at 20?

Note that I used to consider using `template` to have different sizes of `MyArray` in one single binary file, but building two separate executable files is preferable in my case.

Comment: do you want two executables in the same generated buildsystem? Or do you want to generate two buildsystems each with one executable? You haven't specified and have left us to guess. Someone just guessed that you want to former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing specific, add targets and configure them differently.

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

#include "a.h"

int main() {
  fmt::print("Array size: {}\n", sizeof(A::MyArray) / sizeof(double));
}
```

a.h:

```cpp
#include <array>

class A {
 public:
  using MyArray = std::array<double, MY_ARRAY_SIZE>;
};
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(so)

add_executable(myapp-4 a.h main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(myapp-4 PRIVATE MY_ARRAY_SIZE=4)
target_link_libraries(myapp-4 fmtd)

add_executable(myapp-20 a.h main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(myapp-20 PRIVATE MY_ARRAY_SIZE=20)
target_link_libraries(myapp-20 fmtd)
```

Comment: Making me discard my answer :p, well done, this was very quick.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Just used the temple on Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/41xqM74E7

Comment: using `SIZE` as a macro name sounds like a bit of a recipe for trouble or possible later confusion. I'd use `MY_ARRAY_SIZE`.